# Visual Studio version 15.7.1 debugs aspx app in a new chrome instance even if JavaScript debugging is disabled

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

After updating Visual Studio 2017, whenever I debug aspx project, the app launches in a new chrome browser instance.

I have NOT enabled the JavaScript debugger which could have caused this behaviour.

How can I debug from the current active browser instance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uncheck this option under visual studio options..[image]

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!